# Show success or failure message on form.submit()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

As form.Submit() will submit entire for in mvc.
If i want to show success or failure on submit how to show.
I dont want to keep success status in temp data and pass it Get method of form

Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
public void TestAction()
{
  return View()
} 

[HttpPost]
public void TestAction(someData)
{
  // Store data to DB 
  return View()
} 

Script :

$("#btnSave").click(function(){
form.Submit();
});
```

Comment: instead of submitting form use `event.preventDefault()` and make a ajax call and send form data through `form.serialize()` and then send a json token value from httppost testaction actionresult whether data is saved or not and show that token value in alert().

Comment: If your using ajax to submit, there is no point returning the view. Just return a Json containing the message and update the DOM to display it, otherwise add the message to a `ViewBag` property and render it in the view

Comment: Guys i don't want to use Ajax

Comment: then i don't think there is any way to achieve your requirement...with simple form submit the page will postback and refresh which you can't stop...

Comment: Then just add add the message to `ViewBag`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this http://jameschambers.com/2014/06/day-14-bootstrap-alerts-and-mvc-framework-tempdata/

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _people.Add(person);
        Success(string.Format("<b>{0}</b> was successfully added to the database.", person.FirstName), true);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    Danger("Looks like something went wrong. Please check your form.");
    return View(person);
}
```

Comment: AddAlert is using TempData as  i mentioned i don't want to use TempData